# How did Vader restart his suit by himself so quickly?

Tags: star-wars, marvel, comics, darth-vader

In the recent graphic novel *Vader* (I don't know which one), when Darth Vader gets his suit shut down, how was he able to turn everything back on, and then kill that officer? Am I missing something? Has this been addressed in that graphic novel?

Comment: I haven’t read the comic, but to hazard a guess: by pressing the “on” buttons? Is it particularly surprising that Darth Vader knows how to work the suit that his mobility depends on?

Comment: Are you talking about the Vader marvel comics?

Comment: The force, dude, the force!!!

Comment: @Max I said that exact thing outloud  to myself as I clicked into the question :D

Comment: I mean, do you want an answer besides that he obviously used the force?

Answer (score 43):

Vader used the Force to control the kill switch and reactivated his cybernetic suit.

> **Cylo:** Impossible!
>
> **Darth Vader:** Nothing is impossible for the Force.

You're most likely referring to *Darth Vader: End of Games* series by Marvel Comics. In the 23rd issue, Imperial scientist officer Cylo, who also participated in constructing Vader's suit, uses his secret kill switch to disable the cybernetics, as the dark lord was coming to kill him. He had prepared and kept the device "just in case".

[image]

Continued in the 24th issue, while unable to operate, Vader made a mental trip to his history and grew greater in his anger. Raged by the memories of the past, he was able to call for the Dark Side of the Force, and telekinetically control the kill switch button. This activated Vader's armor again and he stabbed Cylo with his lightsaber.

[image]

Comment: I guess you could say he... underestimated the *power* of the dark side!

Comment: You'd think he'd just use the force to move his robo-arms.

Comment: @Gusdor Why? They probably take more force (in the physics sense) to move than a single button.

Comment: @Walt This is the man who can crush throats over skype. I guess I shouldn't expect anything less contrived from a story that takes the most feared villain in a galaxy and gives him an off button.

Comment: @Walt Size matters not.

Comment: Actually he did use the force to move himself initially. I think those images are out of order (you can see Cylo's body on the floor). He uses the force to move himself to kill Cylo, then re-activates his body using the kill switch afterwards.

Answer (score 25):

I can't speak as to the specific circumstances since I haven't seen the novel, but you seem to be forgetting who Darth Vader used to be.

Anakin Skywalker has proven to be a genius engineer. As a kid, he built both C3PO and his own pod racer. When the thing wouldn't start, he very quickly fixed it. (Edit: this happened twice. Once before the race started when JarJar's tongue got paralyzed, and another time when the race started)

So you can assume Anakin's engineering skill to be exceptional. Anakin's genius is continually referenced in The Phantom Menace.

Not only is he a master engineer, but he has also been confined to a machine (the suit) that he needs to stay alive. It seems most likely that he has tinkered with it for as long as he's had the suit. Even if he hasn't made any changes to it, he will at least know how the suit works, down to every intricate little detail (if he can build a functional pod racer from scraps...)

If anyone could manage to restart the suit abnormally quickly; my money is on the genius engineer who has been using the suit for the better part of his life.

**Small edit**
It's a working theory (afaik) that Anakin channeled the Force when he tinkered with machines as a child. That may be the case, but it is irrelevant for this answer.
Whatever compelled him to be an excellent engineer as a child (whether skill, talent or force wielding aptitude), he uses the same when rebooting his own suit.

Comment: +1 also, supporting evidence is found in how often (Legends) material portrayed Luke tinkering with his artificial hand. Like father, like son.

Comment: Luke also fixed C3PO's are pretty fast after he fell off a cliff. A lot of people forget that C3PO loses body parts all the time. Luke put him together quickly in Ben's cave without specialized tools or a run to Lowes. Ben didn't "..remember ever owning a droid..". So why would he keep those kinds of tools around? Luke made do with what he could find, and I don't think anything Ben had stashed in a box to tune his saber would have been the same size or shape. He probably had not used it in years anyway.

Comment: Kylo Ren did not seem to inherit much of granddad's mechanical genius. Vader used the force to rip machines apart in anger and throw them at his kid while fighting. Kylo just rips into everything with his saber using brute force... not The Living Force. Kylo has a helmet because he wants to look like the rest of the family, but all it does is make resistance pilots tease him about his muffled voice. The only thing else it might do is cut off his oxygen, causing him to make rash decisions.

Comment: @Ronk: Kylo is more Han than Luke/Anakin, imo.